# Windows Server Firewall Ports - Unidirectional or Bidirectional?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I want to configure open ports for a firewall (3rd Party Product) to allow communication between a Domain Controller (DC) and a client (and vice versa). OS: Windows 2016/2019. The documentation from Microsoft describes which ports are required for basic services:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/config-firewall-for-ad-domains-and-trusts#windows-server-2008-and-later-versions

Unfortunately, it is silent about the direction in which port sharing must be done.  The firewall is stateful. If I configure the port sharing unidirectional, only the client should initiate the connection and answer the DC. But not the other way around.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, please mark it. This helps other users who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, it is silent about the direction in which port sharing must be done.

The Windows Firewall by default allows outbound traffic. So open inbound traffic to the ports shown in column **Server Port**.

[image]